# Total beginner looking for tutorials programming outlook add ins in c++

Tags: c++, outlook, add-in

I'm an absolute beginner in Outlook programming and Windows GUI programming in general. But I have lots of years experience in C++ programming in general (not GUI)
I need to develop a Outlook plug-in and my question is where to start?
What do I need to know to let me start?
Can you please give me some useful links to learn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OutlookCode.com](http://outlookcode.com/) and it's [forums](http://outlookcode.com/forums.aspx) are always my first point of call with Outlook related programming. Also see the [Office Developer Centre](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/default.aspx).

For your specific scenario the [COM Add-ins](http://outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=36) page links to the following [ATL/C++ sample](http://luifit.net/blogs/jluif/PermaLink.aspx?guid=90da1b84-3ea3-41de-a12c-d457dcc637fb).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Outlook ActiveX library or CDO COM library, the best choose is to use the first one if you are sure user has installed outlook

Comment: where to learn about it is my main question 
tnx

Comment: here is the book, http://c-books.info/books/news6.php/2007/11/30/professional-outlook-2007-programming.html, you can do find in that page there are many other books too

Comment: this site is full with porn popups .. i need some legal links